# Android project-> MainAcitvity.java - R is an undefined variable

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Here's my MainActivity.java class generated when I created an android project. There's a variable R which isn't defined anywhere. I didn't modify this class at all. What should this R variable be assigned to?

```
/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in
 * {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container,
                    PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)).commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
    case 1:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
        break;
    case 2:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
        break;
    case 3:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
        break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You dont need to touch R for any purpose.

Comment: the beggining of the code starts with some imports and     `public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
  NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

 /**
  * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the
  * navigation drawer.
  */
 private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
`     but  couldn't include it cause of that sutpid formatting

Comment: R class is created by Android compiler and it holds things like your Strings, Ids etc. Clean your project and then just import yourpackage.R

Answer (score 1):

This `R` is the name of an auto generated class by your IDE. When you intend to use it, you should import that class in your imports part of your java file.

```
import your.app.pack.R;
```

Which `your.app.pack` is a place holder for your real package name (usually consists of three part separated by dots)

When you declare a resource entity (such as id, string, drawable, ...) in `res` folder, your IDE automatically assign it an integer identifier. and those identifiers in java codes will address to those resources.

Note: If you, after importing, still encounter an error related to this `R`, try clean your project and build it again (or rebuild it)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of questions on here about this kind of issue, I've found the simplest and most effective way to sort it out is to simply delete your auto generated R file and it'll get recreated straight away. You'll obviously also need the import statement as abforce says above.

Answer (score 0):

I once had that problem,too. In my case I had put all the activities into a package and wasn't aware that I have to update the manifest xml about that. Without fixing that the R.java is always imported.

Answer (score 0):

`R` is generated after saving all files, because then the XMLs are parsed and this so-called `resource` class is created. If it cannot be resolved to a variable, that means you probably made a mistake somewhere in your XMLs. If you didn't, then try to clean the project.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this problem. Mostly cleaning the project and building it again resolves the issue. You can check /gen folder to see if the R file is there. Even after cleaning and building the project, if it does not get resolved, then mostly likely any of the files in your /res folder has some error. If there is any error in any file within /res folder, R file does not get generated.

In that case, check your layout files, strings, dimens etc for errors.