# Resources(R) Loading Problem After Android Studio Update

Tags: java, android

I updated `Android Studio` and after that all `R`'s in my codes goes to Red like this:
[image]

I didn't any change in my code and after update this happened. I don't know how to solve it and even I don't know which other information should I provide here to better help.

`Android Studio`'s suggested help didn't help actually!

I did `Clear Project` and `Rebuild Project` the projects but no success. It's about some conflicts? How I have to resolve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android project-> MainAcitvity.java - R is an undefined variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27184470/android-project-mainacitvity-java-r-is-an-undefined-variable)

Comment: Have you tried to import the `R` or not.
If not try to import I think it will do the job.
`import yourprojectname.R;`

Comment: @Spritzig: No, I never import R and my app worked for several years. If i tried to update it doesn't recognize. R here is auto generated file not?

Comment: I have updated a couple of weeks ago and I needed to import the `R` and worked for me.